# Typescript, google.maps.d.ts and type enforcement

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to get the googlemaps typing from https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/googlemaps to enforce types on MapOptions. So given the following bad code:

```
/// <reference path="google.maps.d.ts" />
var map;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: "no, not really", 
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
       mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I was hoping the MapOptions type from google.maps.d.ts would flag the zoom attribute as incorrect. Why isn't `tsc` flagging this as a type error?

Update: tried the following version to include more include more type information for the compiler to chew on, but still no dice:

```
/// <reference path="google.maps.d.ts" />
var map;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions : google.maps.MapOptions = {
    zoom: "no, not really",
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
       mapOptions);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't typed your `mapOptions` variable, and there is no way for the compiler to infer it.

Try `var mapOptions:google.maps.MapOptions = {` (etc).

The interface definition of `zoom?:number` looks good in the d.ts that you reference.

Type inference would work if you created the options as part of the map constructor call:

`map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
       {zoom: 'this-should-fail'});`

... because here the compiler knows the signature of the constructor and can infer the type. In your sample, `mapOptions` is just an untyped object.

**UPDATE**
In VS2012, with WebEssentials 2012 2.7, and TS 0.8.3.1, I get the following:
[image]

...and on hover or in the WebEssentials output panel the error output from TSC is:

> Compile Error.  See error list for details 
>   D:/PROJECT/App/viewmodels/hops/map.ts(147,49): Cannot convert '{ zoom:
>   string; }' to 'google.maps.MapOptions': Types of property 'zoom' of
>   types '{ zoom: string; }' and 'MapOptions' are incompatible

The error comes from the compiler, but I don't know how much of the surfacing is achieved by WebEssentials.

Comment: I've tried both of your variations, and neither is causing tsc to throw a type warning/error. Is there a flag I need to flip to get `tsc` to be more talkative?

Comment: What tool are you using? See update for what I get in VS. Sometimes the tooling does fail (it's alpha, after all) - and you need to compile to get the error.

Comment: I'm using the open source `tsc` [node.js toolchain](http://www.typescriptlang.org/#Download). I'm hoping the type checking half of TypeScript is limited to just the VisualStudio plugin.